# Fazer uma query com o retorno de um Ajax

Tags: ajax, query

Tenho um campo `select` e preciso fazer uma query e carregar o resultado dinamicamente com `Ajax`. Atualmente tenho o seguinte código *(que parece não funcionar ou estar incompleto)*:

```
$('#formProd select').change(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'index.php/home',
        data : {id : $('#formProd select option:selected').val()}
    });                     
});
```

Como eu recebo essa **id** pra que eu faça minha *query*?

Eu quero, ao selecionar uma opção do `select`, que nessa mesma página ele pegue o valor do `select` e faça uma consulta no meu banco de dados pra me trazer os resultados.

Vide [exemplo](http://drop.studiogt.com.br/its/).

Ao clicar em uma categoria, quero que carregue ao lado uma lista com os produtos.

Comment: detalha a sua pergunta. Nos diga em detalhes o que você quer fazer. Por exemplo: onde você quer carregar o resultado? O que está acontecendo na sua query acima que você disse não estar funcionando ou estar incompleto? Coisas assim

Comment: Nesse php quando vc imprimir o `$_POST` ele vem vazio?

Comment: Se a pergunta for: `"Como eu recebo essa id pra que eu faça minha query?"` Simplesmente utilize `$_POST['id']` dentro do arquivo php `'index.php/home'`.

Comment: Não Paulo Roberto, isso não deu certo. Quero saber se o ajax que fiz está correto.

Comment: Correto está, o argumento  `id` vai preenchido olhando pelo firebug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu ajax não faz nada ao completar, porém você deve fazer uma ação da qual seria preencher a sua lista com os elementos retornados desta forma por exemplo:

```js
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url  : 'index.php/home',
    data : {id : $('#formProd select option:selected').val()}
}).done(function() {
  var len = data.id.length; //assumindo que vai retornar um Array.
  var List = []; //lista de elementos retornados
  for(var i=0; i < len; i++){ //percorre a lista de elementos retornados
    List.push("<li>"+data.id[i]+"</li>"); 
  }
  $('#linkList').html(List.join('')); //coloca as li's no ul com os elementos retornados.
});
```

Sobre a Query que você quer fazer, você pode fazer algo do tipo:

```php
$id = $_POST['id'];
if (is_numeric($id))
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM sua_tabela WHERE id='.$id;
```

Note que eu chequei primeiramente se o retorno do `$_POST['id']` é numero, para que não aconteça um SQL Injection em sua aplicação.

Comment: Entendi Paulo. Porém eu so quero fazer uma query do tipo:
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE id = a esse id que eu quero recuperar. Só não sei se faço isso pelo js mesmo ou na pagina php.

Comment: No JS vc não faz a query... a query do Select fica a encargo do php... lá no mysql_query("select * from tabela where id = 6"); por exemplo...

Comment: Sim, com certeza @tchicotti porém o OP não definiu a pergunta muito bem, ele quis dizer como fazer para que meu ajax atualize minha lista (eu acho...)

Comment: @PauloRoberto eu entendi, é por isso que no comentário da pergunta eu pedi uma explicação melhor, mas respondendo ao comentário dele a sua resposta, achei que fosse o que teria mais a ver

Answer (score 4):

Se o problema for enviar o ID do option selecionado via Ajax, o código abaixo deve funcionar sem problemas:

```js
$('#formProd select').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'index.php/home',
        data: { id: $(this).val() },
        //contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        //dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            // utilizar o retorno
        }
    });
});
```

Note que para preencher o valor do ID que deseja enviar você não precisa acessar o valor dessa forma: `$('#formProd select option:selected')`, como você já acessou o componente via o evento "change", basta utilizar o `$(this).val()` para acessar o valor do ID do option selecionado.

Comment: Sobre o `this`, verdade, fica mais prático.

Comment: Porém porque você está especificando que é um json? o OP não disse isto na pergunta.

Comment: Apenas por costume, vou edita-la. E também, pelo que li dos comentários acima, me parece que a pergunta era mais de sql do que ajax.

Comment: Deu certo aqui. A pergunta não era sobre SQL rs. Era sobre como pegar o retorno do Ajax, pois não sei como saber se está retornando algo. Mas já resolvi aqui baseado nessas dicas.

Comment: Que bom! Espero ter ajudado.